# Shortcut key to format Sass files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, sass

In Visual Code I can format typescript, html and css code by using the shortcut key alt+shift+d

How can I use the same shortcut key to format scss files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[JS-CSS-HTML Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter)** or **[Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify)** extension. Then shortcut is **ALT+SHIFT+F**